Retrieve a line with different identifiers
I have a query writing problem. My table:

-> table users_keyword_document

 document_id | users_keyword_id
-------------+------------------
          65 |                1
          65 |                2
          66 |                1
          66 |                3
I want to retrieve only the document with document_id 65
The search can only be done with the user keyword identifiers so users_keyword_id
My query :
SELECT document_id, users_keyword_id
FROM users_keyword_document
WHERE users_keyword_id IN (1,2);
Returns the following result :
 document_id | users_keyword_id
-------------+------------------
          65 |                1
          65 |                2
          66 |                1
Is there an easy way to do this?
I use PostgreSQL.
Thanks for your help.

Sorry, but why not SELECT document_id, users_keyword_id
FROM users_keyword_document
WHERE document_id=65

Because I search with the user keyword identifiers -> users_keyword_id

Then I guess it would be better to somehow rewrite your question to emphasize it

You can use the GROUP BY and HAVING clause method. Can you try this?
Select document_id
from users_keyword_document
where users_keyword_id in (1, 2)
group by document_id
having count(distinct users_keyword_id) = 2;


Yes i tried this method, it's ok :) Thanks

Use HAVING as a condition that works on the group of records:
SELECT document_id
    , ARRAY_AGG(users_keyword_id) AS keyword_ids
FROM users_keyword_document
GROUP BY document_id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(users_keyword_id) <@ ARRAY[1, 2];

